# Why do C# OpenFileDialogs get created off the main GUI thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a c# winforms app that hangs occasionally and I was told that we should make sure we're not opening any windows off the main GUI thread. I fired up Spy++ and noticed that when we open the OpenFileDialog at the beginning of the client session, that dialog exists on another thread, even though the code path is running on the main GUI thread.

Then, after the window is closed, the window still shows up in Spy++ as being on a worker thread. This happens even if we enclose usage of the OpenFileDialog inside a using statement. So it seems that disposing of the dialogue doesn't actually get rid of the Window, which is weird.

Here's the actual code

```
                if (filename == String.Empty)
            {
                using (var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
                    {
                        Filter = string.Format(MessageStrings["DialogFormat"]),
                        Title = MessageStrings["OpenDialogTitle"]
                    })
                {
                    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK || openFileDialog.FileName == String.Empty)
                        return false;
                    filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please post the actual code. This seems unlikely.

Comment: Is your UI thread marked with the STAThread attribute?

Comment: I doubt that dialog box is going to be your problem.  It should be all native code.

Comment: Yes, the UI  thread is marked with the STAThread attribute. I didn't think you could run a UI without that.

Answer (score 3):

No, the dialog is definitely owned by the UI thread in normal usage.  I see no evidence for what you report when you use Spy++.  I wrote several answers here at SO to pull of tricks with the dialogs that can only work when the UI thread owns the dialog window.  Do note that OpenFileDialog creates a very large number of windows so it is easy to get lost in the Spy++ view.  Seeing the window still exist after closing the dialog is otherwise easy to explain, you must use Window + Refresh to force Spy++ to update the snapshot.

Seeing the dialog owned by another thread than your UI thread is otherwise a good explanation for having the kind of trouble you are trying to debug.  The shell dialogs get flaky when you run them on a thread that is not STA.  Sometimes you get an exception but it isn't consistent.  The dialog just failing to show up is indeed a distinct possibility, I've seen this happen.  Use the debugger's Debug + Windows + Threads to look at call stacks to find out why this happened.

Enabling unmanaged debugging lets you see a lot more but do be aware that the shell dialogs themselves add a lot of threads.  You get all the shell extensions loaded into your process, they have a knack for running their own threads.  Those extensions are themselves a chronic source of trouble, use SysInternals' Autoruns to diagnose by disabling them.

Comment: We have only four threads which have windows. The main UI thread which has literally hundreds. Then the one I described in this issue. And then two more which have something about "Default IME". I can get those windows even which the simplest of Winforms apps, so I assume those are ok. Next up we're going to try Hans suggestion from this answer.